# ajax jquery - why this extra slash?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I often see code where the ajax files being contacted (`somefile.php` in the example below) are preceded with a `/`

Is this `/` just to preserve the structure `www.example.com/somefile.php` or is it for security reasons like escaping? If it's the latter, an explanation would also help..

```
$.post('/somefile.php', { id: id, val: val }, function(data) {
      if (something) {
         do something
      } else {
         do something else
      }
   });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It points to the root of the site, just like every other url, in links or images.
For example, if you're on `http://example.com/sub/site.html`, `somefile.php` goes to `http://example.com/sub/somefile.php`, while  `/somefile.php` goes to `http://example.com/somefile.php`